# Is there a reason not to replace `var` with `let` in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

A question for my elders in JavaScript: **putting aside the fact** that [`let` has a different variable scope than `var` does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11444416/99971), it seems to me that in the vast majority of cases, there is no reason to use `var` over `let`. Of course, if you define a variable inside of an `if` statement, it's not the same thing, but is there another reason besides scope to use one over the other?

**Edit**: To be clear, this question is about a best practice (i.e. pros and cons) in JavaScript, **not** about the nature of the differences between `var` and `let`.

Thanks!

Comment: @jedi, no, this one is different

Comment: Duplicate finders overreactive as always :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/let-keyword-vs-var-keyword-in-javascript

Comment: Actually, this was a duplicate. There are differences, do the math. It's no longer a duplicate, because the answer mentions a substantial difference. `let` doesn't leak to `window`. P.S. 'Best practice' questions are 'opinion-based' per se.

Comment: @estus, yes, I mention that in my answer. But with the proper written modular code, no `var` statement should be allowed to leak to `windows` and so this has no importance. And the question is not about differences, it's about whether one should prefer `var` over `let` in ES6 code

Comment: @Maximus Since the question is vague on the environment and doesn't presume that the code is executed inside IIFE or a module, I consider this an important clarification.

Comment: @estus, anyways, I mentioned that in my answer :)

Comment: @estus I don't agree that "best practice" questions are opinion-based. What is sick about Stack Overflow is that all those questions abusers are usually taking questions too directly. "Best practice" means "pros and cons of", but they read it as "what is your opinion on". Many, many great questions have been abused this way here.

Comment: @daveslab, The only reason I can think of not switching everything to let is temporal dead zone. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_dead_zone_and_errors_with_let

Comment: @RoboRobok, I agree that stackoverflow has many problems, including this one that annoys me as well. Besides, I've recently started answering questions and the biggest demotivator is that answer about simple stuff get 3-5 likes, while when I spent an hour going through OP's code or explain in great details  a concept get only one like from the OP at best

Comment: @Maximus True story, my brother. That is screwed up too.

Comment: @YasinYaqoobi, why would you need to declare a variable twice?

Comment: @RoboRobok, and also too many unattended questions. OP asks them and then never gets back for clarification and never accepts an answer. However, I like asking hard questions here and get answers :).

Comment: @Maximus it is not just about declaring the variable twice. There are other edge cases, if you scroll down but i agree, most of these are just bad practice to begin with.

Comment: @RoboRobok Listing pros and cons for each option is one thing. Labeling one of the compared options as 'best' is another. The problem is there can be no pros and cons for this subject, only naked facts.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, I think there are no reasons. From what I've read, the `var` is left in ES6 for backwards compatibility. Most of the articles I've read advise to gradually replace all `var` occurrences with `let`. Of course, this should be done accounting for differences such as the one you mentioned with `if` block. I use only `let` in my ES6 code now. [Eric Elliott doesn't use var either.](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75#.wzk9c6kkc) There’s nothing using `var` that `let` can’t do better. If you need entire function scoping, create the `let` at the top of the function.

There is one difference that I've noticed. It is that when defining variables in the global scope, variables defined as `var` are accessible with `window.variable`, while variables with `let` are not accessible using `window` object. But with the properly written modular code, no `var` statement should be allowed to leak to `window` and so this has no importance.

I would also advise to use `const` instead of `let` for the cases when a variable *reference* (as opposed to a primitive variable's *value*) will not be mutated.